# change text render js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this code in file StudentClasses.aspx:
`<uc1:GroupPick ID="grpPicker" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" />`

And this code in file GroupPick.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="GroupPick.ascx.vb" ClassName="GroupPick" Inherits="DayMap.GroupPick" %>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/daymap/resources/GroupPick.js"></script>  
<div id="selectorMain" style="display:inline-block">
   <span runat="server" id="lblHeader" >List students for: &nbsp;</span>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFilterType" onchange="setFilter(this);" class="jqueryFiterType" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
   &nbsp;
   <select name="ddlGroupCategory" id="ddlGroupCategory" onchange="filterGroups();" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"></select>
   &nbsp;
   <select name="ddlFilter" id="ddlFilter" onchange="setList();" runat="server" class="jqueryFilter" enableviewstate="false"></select>
</div>              
 
<!-- Note for new elements: class="jqueryFiterType" and class="jqueryFiter" cannot be reused -->
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
    ($('select[name$=ddlFilterType] option:selected').index() < 0)
        $('select[name$=ddlFilterType] option[value="0"]').prop('selected', true);
    if ($('select[name$=ddlFilter] option:selected').index() < 0)
        $('select[name$=ddlFilter]').css("display", "none");
</script>
```

line: `<uc1:GroupPick ID="grpPicker" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" />` call the second code, and I want to render the text "list students for" to "list teacher for" but not change the second code. what should I do?

Comment: What exactly is "second code"?

Comment: This is not very clear.  You either need to include more code as context or you need to better describe exactly what you want to change.